# "Кэш онли вступил на целые сутки"?

Tags: заимствования, варваризмы

Мне, к примеру, непонятно. Как бы это обрусить?

> Итальянцы так не готовы работать. Вообще не готовы! Вон вторую неделю
>   роутер крупная компания не может завести. Отрубили в Риме
>   электричество – он и накрылся. Кстати, по району вся линия легла и в
>   кафе или в магазине невозможно было картой расплатиться. **Кэш онли
>   вступил на целые сутки.** И в банкомате было не снять. На неделю
>   квартал парализовало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Закон" наличной оплаты вступил в силу...

Нужно обязательно обозначить грамматический *род* (иначе читателю не додумать, что за зверь такой), даже если  английскими буквами cash only (если итальянцы так буквально написали) или по-итальянски solo contanti.